# Timer still ticking after stop when using AutoReset = False

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I'm using a System.Timers.Timer in a service that seems to keep ticking after it has been disabled.  I'm using autoreset = false so I would expect it to only tick once unless I start it up again.  I'm calling stop again, just for good measure, but the timer keeps on ticking.    I'm using VB.NET in .net 1.1 and don't have the option to change frameworks.

Here is a simple console app to reproduce the issue.  This is not the actual code from the project.  I believe the interval is long enought to prevent any thread issues in raising the event multiple times, but I will admit I'm not a threading expert.

```
Module Module1
Private Timer As New System.Timers.Timer(10000)


Sub Main()
    AddHandler Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Elapsed

    Timer.AutoReset = False
    Timer.Start()

    While True
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Timer Enabled: " & Timer.Enabled)
    End While

End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Timer Tick")
    Timer.Interval = 15000
    Timer.Stop()  'using timer.enabled = false here nets the same effect

End Sub
End Module
```

You can see that the timer will keep on outputting to console indefinitely even after being stopped.  You can press enter to check the value of the timer enabled to confirm that it is false while it is still ticking.  It has something to do with the interval being reset after it has ticked, but I don't understand why it isn't showing as enabled if setting the interval is supposed to turn it back on and why calling stop afterwards doesn't stop it.

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, so any insight would be appreciated.

### Update

It seems that it is the combination of autoreset=false and resetting the interval after the tick.  If I set autoreset=true, resetting the interval doesn't cause problems.  If I take out the interval reset, autoreset=false functions properly.  I've tested this in .net 4 and the issue exists there as well.  I've got a workaround for my project by using autoreset=true and manually turning off the timer immediately after elapsed, but I would really be interested to find out why exactly it works this way.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is evil in many ways.  Which is why System.Threading.Timer exists.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Elapsed event, you should set the [Timer.Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled.aspx) property to false to disable the timer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use stop or enabled = false, I get the same effect.

Comment: Where are you setting the Timer_Elapsed as the event handler?  I think you may need to do this: `AddHandler Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Elapsed`.

Comment: I was using the VB.NET WithEvents/Handles, but I changed it to an addhandler at the start of the function and still get the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are setting the Interval property *after* you tell the timer to stop.  See the remarks on the MSDN page for the AutoReset property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx

Comment: I'm actually setting the interval property before the stop, but I switched it around just to check, but still the same issue.  I don't really see how those remarks apply.  It seems to be saying that I'll have to restart the timer after elapsed with autoreset = false (which is my desired behavior), and that resetting the interval doesn't take into account previously elapsed time.  It doesn't seem to say anything about raising the elapsed event while enabled is false.
Also, I appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You might also read through this thread.

[Which .Net Timer() to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191903/which-net-timer-to-use)

I've had mixed results with System.Timers.Timer, the Windows.Forms.Timer seems to work much more intuitively.